# How do I make this box fade out on a click

Tags: javascript, html

how do you make this box fade out on a click in javascript?  .  Button 3 is where I am having a bit of difficulty.  I'm a neophyte to coding please be patient.

```js
document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", function(){
        document.getElementById("box").style.height = "250px";
    });
        document.getElementById("button2").addEventListener("click", function(){
            document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
        });

        document.getElementById("button3").addEventListener("click", function(){
            document.getElementById("box").style.opacity = "0"
        });

        document.getElementById("button4").addEventListener("click", function(){
            document.getElementById("box").style.height = "150px";
         });
```

```html
<p>Press the buttons to change the box!</p>

    <div id="box" style="height:150px; width:150px; background-color:orange; margin:25px"></div>

    <button id="button1">Grow</button>
    <button id="button2">Blue</button>
    <button id="button3">Fade</button>
    <button id="button4">Reset</button>
```

Comment: You missed `);` for the `button3` block after `}`. Also you missed `});` for the `button4` block. Have a look https://codepen.io/vyspiansky/pen/zYKRLKL?editors=1000

Answer (score 2):

You could just add the [transition](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transition) property to your box element:

```
transition: opacity 1s ease-out;
```

You code also has some syntax errors. You can see a working snippet below:

```html
<div id="box" style="height:150px; width:150px; background-color:orange; margin:25px; transition: opacity 1s ease-out;"></div>

<button id="button1">Grow</button>
<button id="button2">Blue</button>
<button id="button3">Fade</button>
<button id="button4">Reset</button>

<script type="text/javascript">
    document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", function(){
        document.getElementById("box").style.height = "250px";
    });
    document.getElementById("button2").addEventListener("click", function(){
        document.getElementById("box").style.backgroundColor = "blue";
    });

    document.getElementById("button3").addEventListener("click", function(){
        document.getElementById("box").style.opacity = "0"
    });

    document.getElementById("button4").addEventListener("click", function(){
        document.getElementById("box").style.height = "150px";
    });
</script>
```

**Note:** If your project gets bigger, I would recommend to have an external css file for your styles.

Comment: When it resets, it should also reset the fade property instead of just making the height back to normal.

Answer (score 1):

The code you've provided won't make anything "fade", it will cause the `height` to immediately change.  If you want the height to decrease to nothing, causing an effect over time, you can use [CSS transitions](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions) like this:

```js
// Just get your references once.
const box = document.getElementById("box");

document.getElementById("button1").addEventListener("click", function(){
  box.classList.add("bigBox"); // Just add/remove the desired class
});
document.getElementById("button2").addEventListener("click", function(){
  box.classList.add("blue");
});

document.getElementById("button3").addEventListener("click", function(){
  box.classList.add("transparent");
  box.classList.add("noSize");
});

document.getElementById("button4").addEventListener("click", function(){
  // When you remove a class, the prior settings that were
  // overridden by the class are reinstated.
  box.classList.remove("bigBox");
  box.classList.remove("transparent");
  box.classList.remove("blue");
  box.classList.remove("noSize");
});
```

```css
#box { 
  /* You must declare that you want transitions to 
     apply to the element and then you must set
     initial property values for the properties
     you'll want the transition to apply to. 
     If you only want certain properties to transition
     name them on the next line instead of "all" */
  transition: all 3s ease; 
  height:150px; 
  width:150px; 
  background-color:orange; 
  margin:25px; 
  opacity:1;
}

/* These will be added (thus triggering
   the transition) and removed through
   JavaScript. It's better to use classes
   than to use inline styles in HTML. */
#box.transparent { opacity:0; }
#box.bigBox { height:250px; }
#box.blue { background-color:blue; }
#box.noSize { height:0; width:0; }
```

```html
<div id="box"></div>

<button id="button1">Grow</button>
<button id="button2">Blue</button>
<button id="button3">Fade</button>
<button id="button4">Reset</button>
```

Comment: @Spectric ?? This ***is*** JS.

Comment: @Spectric Again, the voting system is there for each person to use, but that doesn't change the fact that your comment didn't make any sense. I'm not really that concerned about 10 points. I'm much more concerned about providing accurate information.

Comment: @Ian You're welcome. Please up vote all helpful answers and consider marking this one as "the" answer by clicking the check mark at the top-left of the answer.

Answer (score 0):

You could use jQuery in your script https://api.jquery.com/fadeOut/ with their fadeout method. You could use something like

```js
    document.getElementById("button3").addEventListener("click", function(){
        $("#box").fadeOut(); // You can optionally add a duration parameter which defaults at 400 ms
    }
```

Comment: The question was not tagged with jQuery and the OP has stated that he's not a strong coder so suggesting that a new technology be added isn't appropriate. Additionally, you didn't even show that/how jQuery must first be added to the page before it can be used.

Comment: @Spectric It's not. We don't want to provide solutions that avoid answering the question that was asked within the parameters of the tags. This isn't a bad suggestion, but it should be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @ScottMarcus I see what you mean, and I agree with your standpoint, but I don't think that warrants a downvote.

Comment: @Spectric That's your opinion and you're welcome to it, which is exactly the reason for the voting system.